# Performing Asynchronous operations on Vaadin UI

Tags: spring-boot, user-interface, asynchronous, vaadin, vaadin-flow

I have a Spring Boot project with Vaadin integration (v14). I want my application to do some background operation and represent the results on the Vaadin-based frontend. For this I have a view which is a Polymer template generated with Vaadin Designer (.js) and connected to a Java companion class. To this view I've just simply added a button initialized with the following listener:

```
        _btnMyTriggerButton.addClickListener(event -> {

        CompletableFuture<Void> c = CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(() -> {
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
            {
                try
                {
                    System.out.println("Waiting");
                    Thread.sleep(1000);
                    UI.getCurrent().access(() -> {
                        Notification.show("Waiting");
                    });
                }
                catch (InterruptedException e)
                {
                }
            }
            return "Waiting over. Greet!";
        }).thenAccept(s -> {
            System.out.println(s);
            UI.getCurrent().access(() -> {
                Notification.show(s);
            });
        });
```

I'm trying to access the UI as the documentation says. However when this is being executed it only reaches the first "Waiting", then stops. If I remove the UI interaction (*Notification.show()*) the output is printed to the backend as desired, but not when attempting do any interaction on the UI..

The structure of my java companion class is the following:

```
@Tag("my-view")
@JsModule("./my-view.js")
@Route("")
@Push(PushMode.AUTOMATIC)
public class MyView extends PolymerTemplate<MyView.MyModel>
{
    @Id("trigger-button")
    private Button _btnMyTriggerButton;

    MyView() {
     // listener initialization code described above
    }
    public interface MyModel extends TemplateModel
    {
    }
```

}

Do I miss something to achieve asynchronous behavior on this webpage?
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem in this case is that the first callback terminates with a `NullPointerException` because `UI.getCurrent()` returns `null` when it's run from a background thread. `CompletableFuture` will just ignore the exception unless you explicitly handle it (e.g. using `handle` instead of `thenAccept`) or block on the result.

You can fix this by adding `UI ui  = UI.getCurrent();` in the beginning of the click listener and then referencing `ui` in both the `supplyAsync` and `thenAccept` callbacks instead of using `UI.getCurrent()` there.

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply, that was it :)